GADTs で型パラメータを使ってないのに書く必要があるのはなぜか？
Generalized algebraic data type - Wikipedia
に下記がありました（{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-} は私が足しました）。

{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- A GADT
data Expr a where
    EBool  :: Bool     -> Expr Bool
    EInt   :: Int      -> Expr Int
    EEqual :: Expr Int -> Expr Int  -> Expr Bool

eval :: Expr a -> a eval e = case e of
    EBool a    -> a
    EInt a     -> a
    EEqual a b -> (eval a) == (eval b)

expr1 :: Expr Bool expr1 = EEqual (EInt 2) (EInt 3)

ret = eval expr1 -- False


下記の部分：

data Expr a where
    EBool  :: Bool     -> Expr Bool
    EInt   :: Int      -> Expr Int
    EEqual :: Expr Int -> Expr Int  -> Expr Bool


a（正しい名称が検索できなかったのですが、型パラメータでしょうか?）を使っていませんが、この aは必要なのでしょうか？
aを削除してみると下記エラーでしたので、必要なのだとは思いますが、使ってないのに必要とは奇妙に思いました。
aを削除したコード：
data Expr where
    EBool  :: Bool     -> Expr Bool
    EInt   :: Int      -> Expr Int
    EEqual :: Expr Int -> Expr Int  -> Expr Bool

エラー：
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, interpreted )

foo.hs:5:27: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Expr’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘Expr Bool’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘EBool’
      In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
  |
5 |     EBool  :: Bool     -> Expr Bool
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^

foo.hs:6:27: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Expr’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘Expr Int’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘EInt’
      In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
  |
6 |     EInt   :: Int      -> Expr Int
  |                           ^^^^^^^^

foo.hs:7:15: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Expr’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘Expr Int’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘EEqual’
      In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
  |
7 |     EEqual :: Expr Int -> Expr Int  -> Expr Bool
  |               ^^^^^^^^

foo.hs:7:27: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Expr’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘Expr Int’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘EEqual’
      In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
  |
7 |     EEqual :: Expr Int -> Expr Int  -> Expr Bool
  |                           ^^^^^^^^

foo.hs:7:40: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Expr’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘Expr Bool’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘EEqual’
      In the data declaration for ‘Expr’
  |
7 |     EEqual :: Expr Int -> Expr Int  -> Expr Bool
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.


この題材は、GADTsでよく見られるようで(?)、GADTs in Scala にも見られれました。
sealed trait Expr[T]
case class IntExpr(i: Int) extends Expr[Int]
case class BoolExpr(b: Boolean) extends Expr[Boolean]

上記はScalaで、やはりTを使っていないようです(Scalaは手元に環境がないのと、不慣れなので、実際には動かしていません。同様にHaskellも不慣れではありますが...）。
a や T が必要なのは、なぜでしょうか？　文法上そこにないと困るのでしょうか？

例えば EBool の型を見てみましょう
Bool -> Expr Bool

ここに出てくる Expr は Bool を引数に取っています。Expr は型をひとつ引数に取ることが分かります。
このことをコードにおいて示すのが
data Expr a where

での a の意味です。もし a がなければ Expr は「引数を取らない型」になってしまいます。
